# Why does this formula to check percentage total fail only sometimes? (SUM(B4:B7)-1)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have inherited a formula that is used to check if a range percentages sum to 100%.

```
=(SUM(B4:B7)-1)
```

If the range is 60%, 20%, 10%, 10% the result is 0 and that's an OK.

If the range is 60%, 20%, 20%, 0% the result is 0 and that's an OK.

But if the range is 50%, 20%, 20%, 10% the result is -1.11022302462516E-16 and that is a FAIL. This is an oddity.

However, if I change it to

```
=(SUM(B4:B7))-1
```

or

```
=SUM(B4:B7)-1
```

If the range is 60%, 20%, 10%, 10% the result is 0 and that's an OK.

If the range is 60%, 20%, 20%, 0% the result is 0 and that's an OK.

But if the range is 50%, 20%, 20%, 10% the result is 0 and that's an OK.

What quirkiness is going on that would give an answer of ?-1.11022302462516E-16

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is not exact in Excel (or any other language), and my guess is that you are really just looking at zero, not completely rounded off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Demo 3.0]

`-1.11022302462516E-16` is not a fail but rather another form of `0` under `General` format in Excel as shown above.

If you change the format of the cell to percentage then you will see 0%. If you try to compare it with 0 or 0% you will get `TRUE` returned which means they are essentially all representing zero in excel.